# I Keep Spawning In The Middle Of Nowhere On A Map

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I recently downloaded a map onto Minecraft and I can get into the world on my game just fine, except that I keep spawning in the middle of nowhere. I have tried looking up coordinates for places on the map and teleporting to them, but it mostly just brought me into the middle of the ocean. I can't find my way to the actual city part of the map and I don't understand why it keeps doing this. :T

Map Download - http://www.planetminecraft.com/project/lapiz-point---modern-city-project/

Comment: Can you link the map in question?

Answer (score 2):

It's more than likely the map creator didn't build the map at the world spawn.  Upon loading the world, being a new player who hasn't entered the world yet, you're spawned at the world spawn. To find whatever the map contains, you're going to have to walk/fly to the build.  If the coordinates are wrong from where you got them online, we cant help you there.  Viewing the world in McEdit chunk view may help you find the build or checking the other players coordinates via an NBT editor (it's more than likely the builder was near his build).